# xml Namespace a security issue

Tags: https, xml-namespaces

My site is served over HTTPS all the time to protect users data, etc.

But, I do have some SVG HTML tags which come with xml Namespace links.  Those links are HTTP NOT HTTPS:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Is this an issue?  Should I make all of these HTTPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not an issue and you should definitely not convert those to https.

To be even more precise, those URIs are even not links, that is a namespace URI of a namespace definition. HTML is not namespace aware, so for HTML they don't have any effect. XML on the contrary is namespace aware and changing even a single character of a namespace URI is comparable to changing the element names. XML is related to this question because SVG is an XML language.